# Род аббревиатуры Q&A

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, род, число, неологизмы

Какой род (или число) у аббревиатуры Q&A в русскоязычном тексте?

Например, как нужно писать: *публичные/публичное/публичная... Q&A*?

Answer (score 2):

В словосочетании всегда есть главное слово, можно подобрать другое обозначение для вашей идеи — например, родовое слово и т. п. Например: "Q&A сайт(ы) / формат / сообщество / система / платформа / программное обеспечение"; "Q&A-заготовка / статья / стиль / формат" в журналистике и т.п. (Зачастую такую аббревиатуру используют также в контексте обеспечения качества, но вопрос, думаю, не об этом.)

В некоторых случаях главное слово понятно из контекста предложения и может быть опущено. Но число и род всё равно определяются этим словом.

Comment: Вопрос совсем не о корректности: контексты типа *подробн?? Q&A* возможны, а какое выбрать окончание – непонятно.

Comment: Так не бывает. Всё равно какое-то слово Вы под этой аббревиатурой понимаете. Если это "отдельная **справка** типа Q&A", используйте женский род, если "**сайт** Q&A" — мужской, если речь идёт об "**обеспечении** качества" (quality assurance, Q&A), тогда средний. Утверждённого правила для Вашего случая нет, эволюционно выживет какой-то из вариантов. Но я бы рекомендовал указывать главное слово.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, нужно относиться к Q&A как к названию, род и число которого не задается самим названием, как например "В огне брода нет". Лучше всего добавлять родовое слово: интересный  фильм "В огне брода нет", интересная картина "В огне брода нет". А если родовое слово не присутствует явно, оно должно быть подсказано контекстом.

Если Q&A - вопросы и ответы, то можно предложить, например,  такой вариант: "Публичное мероприятие в формате Q&A". Возможно, речь о разделе Q&A, который присутствует на многих сайтах. Тогда я бы ориентировался на родовое слово *раздел*.